# How to generate random files and directories that are scattering across the whole partition?

Tags: filesystems, partition, hard-drive

I want to perform a heavy test of using "resize2fs" to shrink the file system. Currently, I have script that creates a few hundred thousand files taking several hundred GB. But it doesn't take very long time to shrink. I think the reason is that those files when created were in adjacent disk areas, such that the "resize2fs" didn't exercise that much. So is there way to scatter files across the whole disk partition? Thanks.

The file system is ext4.

Comment: Which filesystem are you using?

Comment: Please see my new edit.

Comment: Fill the disk with files, then randomly delete some of them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and no.

Yes, it is possible to scatter your files for sure: fill your file system enough (almost full).

No, it's not trivially possible to influence the actual physical distribution of your files to make sure the blocks of a particular file get placed to a certain part of the backing device.

By using [`fallocate`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fallocate.1.html) to preallocate disk space to files, filling the disk is probably a lot faster than by actually writing those data blocks to the disk.